# Testing Snackbar with Espresso

Tags: android-espresso, android-snackbar

I'm testing it using the following:

```
onView(allOf(withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text), withText("Network Error")))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

But it fails on `is displayed on the screen to the user` most likely because the `y` coordinate is `0`: `... x=18.0, y=0.0, ...`

Full log:

```
Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131492981, res-name=snackbar_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=444, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=18.0, y=0.0, text=Network Error, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please add FULL logcat. You put only a part

Comment: That is the most important part, thought. The problem is the snackbar animation starts from Y = 0, and because of that, sometimes espresso do the `isDisplayed` check right away and since Y = 0, it returns false, making the test fails even though the snackbar is present and exists in the correct root. We gave up on this and move to expectation testing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use withEffectiveVisibility instead of isDisplayed so it doesn't matter whether it is actually displayed in the current screen:

```
private void checkSnackBarDisplayedByMessage(@StringRes int message) {
    onView(allOf(withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text), withText(message)))
        .check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(
            ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE
    )));
}
```